# Sort a list with numbers and text in bash

Tags: shell, sorting

How can I sort this output by the numbers?

```
echo "test/app_name_114.sh test/app_name_116.sh test/app_name_117.sh test/app_name_118.sh test/app_anothername_114.sh test/app_anothername_117.sh"
```

And then in reverse order. I expect:

```
test/app_anothername_114.sh test/app_name_114.sh test/app_name_116.sh test/app_anothername_117.sh test/app_name_117.sh test/app_name_118.sh
```

Tried with `sort -t _ -k5`

Comment: What is the expected output for that data and did you try anything?

Comment: I expect "test/app_anothername_114.sh test/app_name_114.sh test/app_name_116.sh test/app_anothername_117.sh test/app_name_117.sh test/app_name_118.sh". Tried with sort -t _ -k5

Comment: You do understand that `sort` will not sort objects on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the spaces with newlines using `tr`, then `sort` then replace them back again:

```
$ echo "test/app_name_114.sh test/app_name_116.sh test/app_name_117.sh test/app_name_118.sh test/app_anothername_114.sh test/app_anothername_117.sh"|tr \  '\n'|sort -t_ -k3.1|tr '\n' \  
test/app_anothername_114.sh test/app_name_114.sh test/app_name_116.sh test/app_anothername_117.sh test/app_name_117.sh test/app_name_118.sh
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!